# How to see logs between right before midnight to right after?

Tags: systemd, systemd-journald

I am trying to see what was logged on my system between "right before midnight" (so the last moments of yesterday), to right afterwards.

```
~ # journalctl --since "2019-09-09 23:59" --until "2019-09-10 00:10"                                                                                                     
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-08-05 09:48:15 CEST, end at Tue 2019-09-10 17:04:00 CEST. --

~ #
```

The output is empty and I am informed that there are logs available since a month ago to now. Why aren't they shown?

A bare `journalctl` shows plenty of logs (starting in August, ending now)

```
~ # journalctl | tail -5
Sep 10 17:10:53 srv synapse[1111]: 2019-09-10 17:10:53,792 synapse.access.http.8008 (...)
Sep 10 17:11:00 srv caddy[1111]: (...)
Sep 10 17:11:02 srv mqtt[1111]: 1568128262: New (...)
Sep 10 17:11:02 srv mqtt[1111]: 1568128262: New(...)
Sep 10 17:11:02 srv mqtt[1111]: 1568128262: Client (...)

~ # journalctl | head -5                                                                                                                                                 root@srv
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-08-05 09:48:15 CEST, end at Tue 2019-09-10 17:13:23 CEST. --
Aug 05 09:48:15 srv systemd[15247]: Stopped target Default.
Aug 05 09:48:15 srv systemd[15247]: Stopped target Basic System.
Aug 05 09:48:15 srv systemd[15247]: Stopped target Paths.
Aug 05 09:48:15 srv systemd[15247]: Stopped target Timers.
```

EDIT 1: There are events in that time range:

```
~ # less /var/log/syslog.1
(...)
Sep 10 00:07:41 srv systemd[1]: Started Session 109446 of user root.
(...)
```

EDIT 2: Interestingly, for another time range I get events, but not from that time range:

```
~ # journalctl --since "2019-09-09 18:00" --until "2019-09-10 19:00"
-- Logs begin at Mon 2019-08-05 09:48:15 CEST, end at Tue 2019-09-10 19:21:44 CEST. --
Sep 10 15:51:26 srv systemd[468]: pam_unix(systemd-user:session): session opened for user root by (uid=0)
Sep 10 15:51:26 srv audit[468]: USER_START pid=468 uid=0 auid=0 ses=146446 msg='op=PAM:session_open acct="root" exe="/lib/systemd/systemd" hostname=? addr=? t
Sep 10 15:51:26 srv systemd[468]: Reached target Paths.
```

Comment: Are you sure there all entries in your 11-minute window? Try testing with a range a little larger. Your command syntax is fine; works as advertised on my Mint 19.2 system.

Comment: @ajgringo619: yes, I updated the question with an example (there are tons of them)

Comment: @ajgringo619: I tried with another time range and, interestingly, there are events but not from that time. In any case I have a continuous stream of events - but that timing part is very strange

Comment: What OS are you running? Try this - `journalctl -S "2019-09-09 18:17:16"` - and see if the results are accurate. If not, I'm not sure where to turn.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

it is because `journald` stores a defined size of log, you can see the current size with

```
journalctl --disk-usage
```

configure this behavior and add many others in

```
/etc/systemd/journald.conf
/etc/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf
/run/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf
/usr/lib/systemd/journald.conf.d/*.conf
```

[source](https://www.freedesktop.org/software/systemd/man/journald.conf.html)

Your default disk size is probably too small to hold 24h logs

Comment: Thank you - yes indeed that was the problem. I also had a rogue file in `/var/log/journal/<id>` from August which held a few log lines and triggered the message of logs starting in August. After removing it I now correctly see the logs starting in the morning of the day (and therefore the surroundings of midnight were unavailable)